# How to protect files from accidental deletion when they must be editable by multiple users?

Tags: linux, security, permissions

Is there a way for multiple users to be able to add, modify, and delete files in a directory (let's call it `/bigproj/`), while protecting these files from accidental deletion? The OS in question is CentOS 7. I do not have root but I can ask my sysadmin to set things up for me. /bigproj does not contain confidential data but the system does, so security is important.

If only one person needed access, the solution would be to set the permissions read-only and run `chmod` before modifying specific files (or use `rm -f` if deleting). However I need multiple people to be able to do this, and only the file owner can do the chmod.

My next idea was to add users to the group "bigproj" , which is given permission to sudo as the user "bigprojadmin". "bigprojadmin" would own all files in the directory.  users could use `sudo -u bigprojadmin` if they wanted to make changes.  However, my sysadmin rejected this proposal as he doesn't want to have an account used by multiple users.

My current best idea is to make "bigprojadmin" a group instead of a user, and use access control lists to grant it write access to the directory. Members of the "bigproj" group would be able to read /bigproj and use `sudo -g bigprojadmin` if they wanted to write. I am worried my sysadmin will reject this as well due to security concerns about the use of sudo, so I'm posting here to see if anyone has a better idea.

To summarize: How can I allow multiple people to freely read files in a directory while enforcing some extra step or confirmation if attempting to overwrite or delete? Ideally without modifying the sudoers file?

Comment: This is really nothing new. Businesses face this daily, but people need to be able to manage their files. Best solution - have good backups to ensure documents are safe from accidental problems.

Comment: You have to determine if the users require permissions to change the file.  If that is the case then there are very little protections on any operating system from a user with write permissions to delete the file. On any any modern operating system it is trivial for a user to overwrite a file with another file that doesn't contain any data. Some operating systems like Windows can be configure so the file cannot be deleted, but the file could be replaced with another file, that does not have any data contained within it.  So you are left to use source control and/or file versions (shadow copy).

Comment: What does it matter?  By allowing them to make the file "empty".. what is the difference?  You are screwed either way.  @Ramhound and John are both on to the answer.. please read the comments above.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - Who was your comment directed towards?  (I mention overwriting a file with a blank file because I did that on a Solaris system when downloading a file through FTP.  Apparently just attempting to download a file created a shadow file, but the file that was being downloaded didn’t exist, so it replaced a file with data with a blank file).  I am a very experienced Administrator on multiple systems and even I made a mistake.  So an EMD, shadow copies, or version control systems are very helpful

Comment: @Ramhound, it wasn't directed at ANYONE .. I was trying to support your comments.. it doesn't matter of you can delete or not if you can overwrite a file with 0 bytes.. Again.. backup / source control is the only way to be sure that you aren't screwed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way for multiple users to be able to add, modify, and
> delete files in a directory (let's call it /bigproj/), while
> protecting these files from accidental deletion?

I spent time thinking about this, and also reflecting on the inevitable deletions and damage over the years at many small business clients.

If a person can save a file, they can change it or delete its contents.

Accordingly:

1. This is primarily a business management issue.
2. Technology and systems cannot stop a legitimate user with "save" capability from accidentally deleting file contents.
3. So:  the very best protection (widely used) is very good backups.  This will solve your main issues.

You may wish to have protected folders for some very important documents but this is secondary and limited protection as even users of protected folders need to save documents.

Comment: We do have backups, and they recently saved us some trouble when someone did accidentally delete something.  That got me trying to think of a way to add an extra layer of safety - something like sudo, which helps prevent a legitimate administrator from wrecking everything with an accidental "rm -rf /"

Comment: You can have a protected folder for very sensitive things, but backups remain the best protection.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of such an option but a solution to the problem could be using an EMD (document management software) system AND a backup solution. Most collaboration systems save file revisions, create backups and preserve deleted files for some time allowing you easy recovery.

Possible solutions include Google Drive, OneDrive, Zoho, OwnCloud/NextCloud, etc ...

Comment: You have a point, but in my case the shared project is both fairly large (10+ TB) and security is a concern (non-HIPAA/anonymized medical data) so cloud services aren't ideal.  Solutions like DataLad exist for version control in this context, but I didn't want to force the whole team to learn how to use them.